# SQL::Self join a table to satisfy a particular condition?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM temp;
+----+------+
| id | a    |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 | 
|  2 |    2 | 
|  3 |    3 | 
|  4 |    4 | 
+----+------+
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | a    | a    |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    2 | 
|  2 |    2 |    3 | 
|  3 |    3 |    4 | 
+----+------+------+
```

but I am having a small problem. I wrote the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT A.id, A.a, B.a FROM temp A, temp B WHERE B.a>A.a;
```

but my output is the following:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | a    | a    |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    2 | 
|  1 |    1 |    3 | 
|  2 |    2 |    3 | 
|  1 |    1 |    4 | 
|  2 |    2 |    4 | 
|  3 |    3 |    4 | 
+----+------+------+
```

Can someone tell me how to convert this into the desired output? I am trying to get a form where only the consecutive values are produced. I mean, if 2 is greater than 1 and 3 is greater than 2, I do not want 3 is greater than 1.

Comment: Are the numbers in `a` consecutive with no gaps or just ordered and may have gaps?

Comment: @Martin: Oh.. no they need not be consecutive. They may have gaps.

Comment: @OMG: Yeah. If that is what they call this :)

Comment: `SELECT A.id, A.a, B.a FROM temp A, temp B WHERE B.a>A.a GROUP BY A.a;` seems to be giving me what I want but am not sure if this is right... Any comments?

Comment: er actually I think `SELECT A.id, A.a, MIN(B.a) AS a FROM temp A JOIN temp B ON B.a>A.a GROUP BY A.id, A.a;` would do it.

Comment: I like this one better... :) Short and sweet... Thanks a ton... Could you add this as an alternate solution to your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1: "Triangular Join" - Quadratic Complexity**

```
 SELECT A.id, A.a, MIN(B.a) AS a 
 FROM temp A 
     JOIN temp B ON B.a>A.a 
 GROUP BY A.id, A.a;`
```

**Option 2: "Pseudo Row_Number()" - Linear Complexity**

```
select a_numbered.id, a_numbered.a, b_numbered.a
from 
(
select id,
       a,
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rn
  from temp
  join (select @rownum := 0) r
order by id

) a_numbered join (
select id,
       a,
       @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 as rn
  from temp
  join (select @rownum2 := 0) r
order by id

) b_numbered 
on b_numbered.rn = a_numbered.rn+1
```

Comment: When I execute your query, I get just one row: 4, 4,1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @legend - I needed to use a different variable name in the `option2`. I thought it would be reset but clearly not. Fixed now! You may well find that this second version performs better if you have a large table as the workload will grow linearly not quadratically as in option 1.

Comment: Thank you very much and +1 for the explanation too! :)